# Powershell - send remote site arguments?

Tags: sockets, powershell, scripting, teamcity, tcpclient

I'm trying to get powershell to send a remote site ?blah=x arguments (query data).

In a browser it works fine //site.com:111/?run=True , I get an output. When trying to curl the address it fails, and when trying to use system.net.sockets.tcpclient I'm either doing something wrong or it's not working either.

Suggestions?

sockets.tcpclient only seems to allow "server" / "port" and not stream information.

```
$tcpConnection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($HostServer, $HostPort)
```

Comment: "When trying to curl the address it fails" - in what way? Does it throw an error message? Returns an http error code?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
curl : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://site:111/?run=True
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Are you talking about a website when you say site?  If so, why are you using a TCP client instead of the built in PowerShell HTTP commandlets.  Invoke-WebRequest, for example?  Also, those errors show that you have more basic issues than this - make sure you can resolve the hostname and use telnet to test the port.

Comment: @ChrisN
Yes it is a website not a local system.

Comment: The `TCPClient` class does have a `GetStream` method, maybe you should be using that?